# Ubuntu raid configuration lost after reboot

Tags: raid, disk, disk-utility

I have a JMicron raid controller on the motherboard, and I have a menu in which I can set RAID arrays when the system boots. I've set it to RAID-1 and added my two identical 2TB disks (the OS disk is separate).

In Ubuntu, in the Disk Utility, I could see these 2 hard disks and I could see an additional entry under Peripheral devices which was a 2TB disk. I assumed that this is some sort of a virtual view over my RAID array.

I used the Format Volume option to format (NTFS) the 2TB disk listed under Peripheral devices. It appeared as a mounted device in the `/media/data_raid`. I've copied most of the files there and it worked fine.

I've rebooted the system, and now I suddenly see an additional 3 disks in peripheral devices, which doesn't make sense. Also, I can no longer mount the `/media/data_raid` - clicking on it in Gnome yields the following error message.

```
"One or more block devices are holding /dev/dm-0"
```

This is how things look in Disk Utility:

[image: the original drive]

[image: the newly appeared drive]

There are additional 3 entries in `/dev/mapper` for some reason:

```
~$ ls -l /dev/mapper
total 0
crw------- 1 root root 10, 236 2012-05-01 20:01 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 2012-05-01 20:15 isw_bjcjaghhjj_DATA -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 2012-05-01 20:01 isw_bjcjaghhjj_DATA1 -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 2012-05-01 20:01 isw_bjcjaghhjj_DATA2 -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 2012-05-01 20:01 isw_bjcjaghhjj_DATA3 -> ../dm-3
```

Can you help me resolve this issue and obtain access to my RAID array again?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a fresh installation of 12.04 or did it already work with this version? Because I had problems with my RAID too, after first boot.

Comment: This is Ubuntu 11.10. I did not update to 12.04 yet.

Comment: @Bevor: What did you have to do with 12.04?

Comment: @KyleBrandt That was my problem:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37567/sda-and-sdb-block-specials-point-to-same-device-and-get-mixed-up-hardware-raid

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue, trying to partition/format two 2TB RAID0 disks.
I'm running hardware raid set in bios because I've read it's faster than software raid and doesn't load the CPU as software raid does.

I installed GParted and with that I could make a partition and format the RAID disks.